# change Button Position in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, button, position

change the position of ‘activate deal’ button like ‘show coupon’ button.

i am using this code for the position of ‘show coupon’ button.

```css
div.folding-button {
  position: relative;
  left: 610px;
  Bottom: 150px;
}
```

i have tried to change the position of ‘activate deal’ button by using the code :

```css
a.deal-button.activate-button.activate-modal {
  position: relative;
  left: 610px;
  Bottom: 150px;
}
```

but the ‘show coupon’ button got distorted and ‘activate deal’ button is not clickable

Thanks. help is aprreciated

Comment: Hello could you please provide url of website where I could test it? It would be much much easie to find a solution. So you are trying to set activate deal to the right same as show coupon button right?

Comment: Yes @LuboMasura. exactly same i want to do.  https://coupons.indus1one.com/coupons/

Comment: Please edit your question with more explanation what do you need to do because on your screenshot I do not see any sidebar but on your url there is a sidebar and I dont clearly understand what do you want to do.

Comment: @LuboMasura sidebar is removed. i just want to place ‘activate deal’ button like ‘show coupon’ button. As you can see in the website

Comment: You use any plugin or did you write this code on your own?

Comment: @LuboMasura i had provided above the css codes for styling.

Comment: There is not a css problem. There is a HTML problem.Thats why Im asking if you have coded this or you use plugin. Im trying to find a solution.

Comment: https://coupons.indus1one.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/21.png

Comment: @LuboMasura i had only added css for styling in theme and nothing else.

Comment: Ok let me write a solution bellow

Comment: ok @LuboMasura thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reviewed your code and your problem is that you have only one HTML class for button and 1 main class it there is a coupon in it. If you sort there 2 buttons with 2 different classes and put them into a div of right content you could find a better solution than with css.

Anyway I have done some css research on your website and I have found this solution with css. Try following code bellow and make it responsive for each screen to make it work great. I have tested it with 1920px width screen and it works great.

```
a.deal-button.show-coupon-button.activate-button.activate-modal{
    position: relative;
    left: 38rem;
    top: -10rem;
}
a.deal-button.activate-button.activate-modal {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    left: 38rem;
    top: -10rem;
    z-index: 2;
}
.code-button-bg {
    position: relative;
    left: 38rem;
    top: -12.5rem;
    background: #a41913;
}
```

To prevent title shows behind the button put this into your css

```
h2.title.front-view-title {
    width: 75%!important;
}
```

Comment: thanks you very much @LuboMasura . it worked greatly.

Comment: No problem, could you please mark my answer as right solution please? :) Glad to hear that helped! @DimensionWave

Comment: just help me a little more @LuboMasura what to do for the text that is hiding inside the button https://coupons.indus1one.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/dcjbjd.png

Comment: limit the text to the position and then in the next line . it should not hide inside the button

Comment: All my promblem solved ! thanku very much @LuboMasura . i have market your answer as the right solution.

Comment: Thank you. Glad to hear your problem is solved. Good luck with your project. @DimensionWave